# Grails special characters in URL not working

Tags: grails

I am trying to call some urls with special characters in it. But it does not work.
This works:
GET .../rest/validation/checknameunique/?className=lomnido.Template&rename=true&name=Templaa%3Ea

This not: PUT ../rest/template/rename/526/Templaa%3Ea
There I get a 400 back from grails.
In the NGINX Log there is this entry

```
213.162.73.171 - - [22/Apr/2022:13:16:32 +0000] "PUT /rest/template/rename/28484/Bla%3Eaa HTTP/1.1" 400 2307 "https://mytest.com/configuration/template/28484" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"
```

When I debug this, the request does not reach the Security Interceptor (all requests go through this).

What is wrong here?

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: What happens if you `POST` to `/rest/template/rename/28484/Bla`?

Comment: This works: https://myurl/rest/template/rename/450/?newName=Test%3E

But this works not: https:/myurl/rest/template/rename/450/Test%3E

The Entry in the UrlMapping: 

 "/rename/$id/$newname" {
                    controller = "RestTemplate"
                    action = [GET: "rename", PUT: "rename"]
                }